# How to bind INamingContainer control in ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, model-binding

I am creating custom `HtmlHelper` that generates some web controls on my page like `Panel, Label, TextBox and DropDownList`. My Panel is `INamingContainer` so I can group up the elements on the page.

**Here is a code sample:**

```
class MyPanel : Panel, INamingContainer
        {
        }

public static MvcHtmlString Panel(this HtmlHelper html)
        {
            Panel pnl = new MyPanel();
            pnl.ID = "mainPanel";
            pnl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
            pnl.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(1);
            pnl.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

            Label lblTitle = new Label();
            lblTitle.Text = "Title";
            TextBox txtTitle = new TextBox();
            txtTitle.ID = "txtTitle";
            lblTitle.Attributes.Add("for", "txtTitle");

            Label lblMessage = new Label();
            lblMessage.Text = "Message";
            TextBox txtMessage = new TextBox();
            txtMessage.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
            txtMessage.ID = "txtMessage";

            Label lblDepartment = new Label();
            lblDepartment.Text = "Department";
            DropDownList lstDepartment = new DropDownList();
            lstDepartment.ID = "lstDepartment";
            ListItemCollection collection = new ListItemCollection();
            collection.Add(new ListItem("Department1"));
            collection.Add(new ListItem("Department3"));
            collection.Add(new ListItem("NoDepartment"));

            lstDepartment.DataSource = collection;
            lstDepartment.DataBind();

            pnl.Controls.Add(lblTitle);
            pnl.Controls.Add(txtTitle);
            pnl.Controls.Add(lblMessage);
            pnl.Controls.Add(txtMessage);
            pnl.Controls.Add(lblDepartment);
            pnl.Controls.Add(lstDepartment);

            HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter());
            pnl.RenderControl(writer);

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(writer.InnerWriter.ToString());
        }
```

Now, I need to bind this elements in my controller. What I get (as HTML code) when I execute the application (from the above code) is this:

```
<div id="mainPanel" style="border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;">
        <span for="txtTitle">Title</span>
        <input name="mainPanel$txtTitle" type="text" id="mainPanel_txtTitle">
        <span>Message</span>
        <textarea name="mainPanel$txtMessage" rows="2" cols="20" id="mainPanel_txtMessage"></textarea>
        <span>Department</span>
        <select name="mainPanel$lstDepartment" id="mainPanel_lstDepartment">
            <option value="Department1">Department1</option>
            <option value="Department3">Department3</option>
            <option value="NoDepartment">NoDepartment</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

What arguments I should expect, and how to bind them?

**EDIT:**

I have created some partial Razor view's in the `Editor Templates` folder.
**_TicketTitle.cshtml**

```
@model TicketSystemMVC.Models.Ticket

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Title)
```

After that in my **model**, I did this:

```
namespace TicketSystemMVC.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class Ticket
    {
        public Ticket()
        {
            this.Ticket_Message = new HashSet<Ticket_Message>();
        }

        public int TicketID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5)]
        [UIHint("_TicketTitle")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(400, MinimumLength = 5)]
        [UIHint("_TicketMessage")]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Active ticket?")]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Created on")]
        public System.DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public int AccountID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [UIHint("_TicketDepartment")]
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Ticket_Message> Ticket_Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What I do in the **controller** is this (just simple code to debug and check the values)

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Ticket ticket)
        {
            string title = ticket.Title;
            string message = ticket.Message;
            string dep = ticket.DepartmentID.ToString();

            return View();
        }
```

The **view**:

```
@model TicketSystemMVC.Models.Ticket
@using TicketSystemMVC

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create new ticket";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Ticket</legend>

        @Html.Panel()

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Go back", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I *THINK* (if I am wrong, please tell me and I delete this answer) what you want to achive can be done easily via [editor templates](http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/):

1. Create a partial view named e.g. `ListItemPanel` in `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`
2. Define its model like `@model string` (or whatever fits your type)
3. "fill the template" like:

   `<div id="mainPanel" style="border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;">
           <span for="txtTitle">@Html.LabelFor(m => m)</span>
           <input name="mainPanel$txtTitle" type="text" id="mainPanel_txtTitle">
           <span>Message</span>
           <textarea name="mainPanel$txtMessage" rows="2" cols="20" id="mainPanel_txtMessage"></textarea>
           <span>Department</span>
           @Html.DropDownFor(m => m)
   </div>`
4. In your view you then can do something like:

   `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Department, "ListItemPanel")`

In your `[HttpPost] public ActionResult Create(MODEL model)` you then get the correctly mapped values in e.g. `model.Department`.

*ATTENTION: This is just a basic "way to go" example and not "production ready copy & paste code"!*

Comment: Can someone tell me how I can get the HTML code-block formatted correctly? Without the "inline-style", when using a "normal code-block" all HTML was removed from the output...

Comment: In this `<div id="mainPanel" ..>`, the `id` is typed just for the purpose of the example. When I will have to implement this, the `id` field will be generated automatically. How I will do than the mapping with the model, when I don't really know his value?

Comment: There are severaly ways: Pass it in via the `ViewBag` (e.g. `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Department, "ListItemPanel", new { Id = "myId" })` and `<div id="@ViewBag.Id" ..>`) or use some "naming convention" like `<div id="mainPanel_@Html.IdFor(m => m)" ..>` (then the panel will get something like `mainPanel_Department` as its id). As I said: This code is just a "starting point" and you can extend it to your needs - I have editor templates with >10 values passed in via the `ViewBag` and >50 lines of "template code" here (I also created `HtmlHelper` extensions to build that `ViewBag`)...

Comment: ... e.g. I have a Helper I can call like `@Html.DropDownEditBlockFor(m => m.MyValue, Model.MySelection, LabelSize.Large, placeholder: "optional", toolTip: "My Tool-Tip")` which then prepares the `ViewBag` and calls my editor template.

Comment: I was talking about the model. How can I know the exact names so I can code the model? When I am doing model binding, the `id`'s from the `<input ..>` and so on match the exact names in the model so I do the auto mapping.

Comment: The HTML Helpers take care of that - e.g. `@Html.DropDownFor(m => m)` inside the editor template will create the correct id so it is mapped back to the model on post-back. That is the reason you need to use editor templates and not e.g. partials, because the id's are not correct if you do not use them...

Comment: @ChriFin I am trying to do what you told me, but I can't display that partial views. I have done `Editor Templates` and everything as you told me, but in the end when I run the application I don't see the form fields except the submit button.

Comment: @ChriFin Found my mistake, but I can't bind the data again. I am inputting some values into the fields, submit that form and still in the controller get null's.

Comment: Please update/change the question and add how you do it now so I can see. I use this approach very successful here so it should work fine IF used correctly (can be tricky in some cases)...

Comment: Can you also show me the `_TicketTitle` template and your post-back action? So far it looks correct...

Comment: The code under the `_TicketTitle.cshtml` is what I have inside the partial view. Updated the `HttpPost` controller too.

Comment: For the model binder to work you need to "supply the model": `public ActionResult Create(TicketSystemMVC.Models.Ticket model)` - then `model.Title` should contian your value...

Comment: It's all null again, nothing changed.

Comment: Pleas show your complete Model, View, editor-template and Action. Something must be wrong as the general approach should work...

Comment: You are not using what I told you, so it can't work (if you posted your current code)! `public ActionResult Create(TicketSystemMVC.Models.Ticket model)` instead of `public ActionResult Create(string txtMessage, string txtTitle, string lstDepartment)` and `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DepartmentID)` (and also for the other properties) instead of `@Html.Panel()` (especially the `EditorFor` is required for the model binding to work)...

Comment: I wrote on the post that I have to use web controls, and I call them with the `@Html.Panel()`. Also, it is not important whether I change the attributes or not, still doesn't do the mapping. I will edit it now, but you will see it won't work again as I have tried that. And with what should I change the `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DepartmentID)` property?

Comment: Maybe you did not get the main point of my approach: Do NOT use `@Html.Panel()`, but e.g. `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DepartmentID)` with an appropriate editor template instead. Otherwise the model binder will not be able to map the values back to your model.

Comment: If you do not want to use this approach you can also use the e.g. `Html.IdFor(m => m.DeprtmentID)` to set the correct id for input elements you generet with some other logic (like your `@Html.Panel()` -> `@Html.Panel(Html.IdFor(m => m.DepartmentID))` and `public static MvcHtmlString Panel(this HtmlHelper html, string id)`)...

Comment: I have to use that approach. I need to have `HtmlHelper` that creates `web controls` on my application. Let's say I have one `framework` that generate those `web forms`. That's why I am generating `web forms` like that, so I can find some way to get values and bind them with the model. :)